# QString returning different sting on same compilation (but different systems)

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I need to install a lib that uses Qt on an old machine that runs openSuse 11 i586. Actually, my build machine runs Ubuntu and we have our own Qt compilation - in order to use static feature. Apparently, both machines (build and target) has compatible systems.

All work fine, excepting for QString. On target machine QString prints strange characters.

```
QTextStream out(stdout);
QString text = "ABCDEFGHJKLNOPQRSTUWXYZ \n";
out << text;
```

For example, the code above results this on target machine:

> ABCDEFGHEFGHSTUWXYZ

Is there any trick to solve this? Maybe something related to charset. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could be a file encoding issue. Try wrapping your string literal in the [QStringLiteral macro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral)

Comment: What's shown by `std::cout << text.toStdString()`?

Comment: @jpo38 shows same output (ABCDEFGHEFGHSTUWXYZ ). The warning QT_MESSAESSAWARNING:ING: now is printed after toStdString()

Comment: @MrEricSirQStringLiteral did not solve. Same output too.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, your executable must ideally not dynamically link to anything at all. Most likely you're facing binary incompatibility between some glibc or libgcc magic sauce between your system and the target system. Configure Qt with `-static-runtime` - I bet it'll work then.

Comment: I'm already using -static on Qt configure. You mean my lib+exe should use static too?

Comment: There's a rather fundamental difference between `-static` and `-static-runtime`.